# `bookdown site` generation via `blogdown`

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, blogdown

My question is understanding whether the bookdown book can be generated with blogdown.

In reading https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/, and looking at https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/tree/master/inst/examples/Makefile, it seems everything is built from:

```
  cmd = sprintf("bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', '%s', quiet = %s)", fmt, quiet)
  res = bookdown:::Rscript(c('-e', shQuote(cmd)))
```

The code of which seems to be in `R/render.R`

Looking at the code, it seems it generates a book that can be viewed within RStudio IDE, or can be used as a static site via https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/github.html

What is not clear is if there is a way to do the same with `blogdown`, i.e. generating the hierarchies of a book (chapters/sections/etc) and have the theme stitch them together in a table of contents via `hugo`.  It seems that https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium doesn't have that capability.   So I am guessing that generating the bookdown book via `blogdown` is not feasible at this point.

Comment: Also see https://community.rstudio.com/t/converting-blogdown-site-to-bookdown-pdf/2767/2. This won't be straightforward if your posts use external files, and these file paths may need to be adjusted when you stitch the posts together.